# Combining two formulas in one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have two cells in my excel workbook that contain vba to perform a formula. What I'm trying to do is put two formulas in one cell instead of two separate ones. I have provided the code below for what I have so far. The outcome I want in cell C1 is to say "AMTS:(count) Cleaners:(count)" both together not separate. I tried just putting the & between the formulas and it kept returning a false value lol. 
Thanks!

```
ws.Range("$C$1").Formula = "=""AMTs:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""AMT"")&"")"""
ws.Range("$D$1").Formula = "=""Cleaners:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""Cleaner"")&"")"""
```

Comment: I am guessing that you've forgotten to remove the equal sign, or that there may be some issues with too many apostrophes. Try `ws.Range("$C$1").Formula = "=""AMTs:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""AMT"")&"") Cleaners:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""Cleaner"")&"")"""`

Comment: works perfect I had way too many apostrophes lol Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.Range("$C$1").Value = "=""AMTs:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""AMT"")&"")""" & "=""  Cleaners:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""Cleaner"")&"")"""
```

[image]

This is the output from the macro.

or

```
ws.Range("$C$1").Formula = "=""AMTs:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""AMT"")&"")  Cleaners:("" & COUNTIF(E:E,""Cleaner"")&"")"""
```

Comment: who marked me down for this? It works and does exactly what they asked.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this answer is not correct so I can understand why. You have the right idea, but several things are wrong with it.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, and it doesn't even try to explain what the initial problem is. At best it is better suited as a comment.

Comment: Re: your edit: the formula works on the sheet, but the VBA-snippet you posted won't. You need to use `.Formula`, not `.Value`, and you have to remove the surplus `=`. See @eirikdaude's comment to the question-asker.

Comment: i didnt input the formula to the sheet. i ran the macro and it set the value of the cell to the formula.

Comment: i originally didnt notice @eirikdaude comment as it wasn't showing when i answered. Have marked you up as it is the same answer that i gave but with the added explanation of what went wrong. (I.e. quotation marks). which i do agree makes your answer more wholesome, in depth and all-round better than mine.